# Axios not returning response with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a redux-saga as follows.
When I trigger this saga. I see `Initiated request` in my console, but not the response.
If I check my network tab, I can see that request has been completed. What I am missing?

Also, there aren't any console errors

```
function* initateGoogleLogin() {
  const loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_login_url';
  console.log('Initiating requst');
  const response = yield call(axios, { url: loginUrl, method: 'GET' });
  console.log(response);
}
```

[image]

[image]

I updated the above code with `try/catch/finally` as follows

```
function* initateGoogleLogin() {
  const loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_login_url';
  try {
    console.log('Initiating requst');
    const response = yield call(axios, { url: loginUrl, method: 'GET' });
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    console.log('finally');
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      console.log('task got cancelled');
    }
  }
}
```

Still, the console shows only `Initiating Request`

If I click the button again, the previous saga gets cancelled and again it gets stuck at `Initiating requst`

Comment: Can you show how you're triggering the saga?

Comment: @NicholasTower I am using `yield takeLatest(INTIATE_GOOGLE_LOGIN, initateGoogleLogin)` to trigger the saga. 
I have an action with type `INTIATE_GOOGLE_LOGIN` which is dispatched on a button click

Comment: My guess is that the saga is being cancelled somehow, but i don't really see how. `takeLatest` *can* cancel the saga, but if that happened i'd expect it to run again. Can you try wrapping the `yield call` in a `try/catch/finally`, with logging in both the catch case and the finally case? If it enters the catch, then an error happened. If it enters the finally, then the saga was apparently canceled (you can double check by doing checking `yield cancelled()` in the finally)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, i'm pretty stumped. From the symptoms, it looks like the promise never resolves (nor rejects). But given the info in the network tab, it should have resolved. Are you using any axios interceptors?